# Maven hangs at compiling,my project use java 11, how to fix it?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

my project use java 11,when i use "mvn clean compile -X -e",then it hang at here:

```
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/liuxu/IdeaProjects/papaya/papaya-promotion-taoke-starter/target/classes
```

nothing happen,hangs at here.  The project is spring boot application.

this is my compiler configuration:

```
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
  <buildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <compilePath default-value="${project.compileClasspathElements}"/>
  <compileSourceRoots default-value="${project.compileSourceRoots}"/>
  <compilerId default-value="javac">${maven.compiler.compilerId}</compilerId>
  <compilerReuseStrategy default-value="${reuseCreated}">${maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy}</compilerReuseStrategy>
  <compilerVersion>${maven.compiler.compilerVersion}</compilerVersion>
  <debug default-value="true">${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
  <debuglevel>${maven.compiler.debuglevel}</debuglevel>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
  <executable>${maven.compiler.executable}</executable>
  <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.compiler.failOnError}</failOnError>
  <failOnWarning default-value="false">${maven.compiler.failOnWarning}</failOnWarning>
  <forceJavacCompilerUse default-value="false">${maven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse}</forceJavacCompilerUse>
  <fork default-value="false">${maven.compiler.fork}</fork>
  <generatedSourcesDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations"/>
  <maxmem>${maven.compiler.maxmem}</maxmem>
  <meminitial>${maven.compiler.meminitial}</meminitial>
  <mojoExecution default-value="${mojoExecution}"/>
  <optimize default-value="false">${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
  <parameters default-value="false">true</parameters>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
  <projectArtifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
  <release>11</release>
  <session default-value="${session}"/>
  <showDeprecation default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
  <showWarnings default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
  <skipMain>${maven.main.skip}</skipMain>
  <skipMultiThreadWarning default-value="false">${maven.compiler.skipMultiThreadWarning}</skipMultiThreadWarning>
  <source default-value="1.6">${maven.compiler.source}</source>
  <staleMillis default-value="0">${lastModGranularityMs}</staleMillis>
  <target default-value="1.6">${maven.compiler.target}</target>
  <useIncrementalCompilation default-value="true">false</useIncrementalCompilation>
  <verbose default-value="false">${maven.compiler.verbose}</verbose>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What maven.compiler.source version have you in projects properities in pom.xml defined?

Comment: Have you tested with JDK8 and looked where it exactly hangs ? In a Test during the compilation?

Comment: @khmarbaise compiled with JDK8 ; all passed no hangs

Comment: So now we can continue. Where does the build hang? And how?

Comment: @khmarbaise switched the jdk version to 11,Then the compiling hangs at a maven module that contains 3rd jars. the jars is compiled with jdk 6 , or maybe is jdk 7.

Comment: Can you explain that more in detail? What does `hang` mean? Logging output? Error message ? Maybe you have a download issue while trying to download an other dependency?

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry,i'm not English native speaker. in the case,the `hang` represent the maven  staying in compile phase. this is the Logging output: `[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/liuxu/IdeaProjects/papaya/papaya-promotion-taoke-starter/target/classes `. compile cannot finish. compile with java 8, it's work fine with no error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have correctly defined the Java version in projects properities in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Secondly check if the plugin version is configured as follows (also pom.xml):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>11</release>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I already set compiler parameters to java 11, same like your posts, and it's still hangs

Comment: [DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/liuxu/IdeaProjects/papaya/papaya-promotion-taoke-starter/target/classes

Comment: somethings weird, the another maven module compiled without hang,that maven module is pure java project without 3rd jar. this maven module 'papaya-promotion-taoke-starter' has low version java jars. Is that possible?  sorry! my English sucks.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem, but much more strange. If built manually (manual execute mvn build command from ssh session), it was successful. But if we use a shell script to build, it hangs at maven compiler plugin). After inspecting the calling stack, we found that the javac process hangs at `java.lang.Shutdown.halt0(int)` waiting for shutdown lock. Which means, shutdown has been called in the same jvm instance.
Problem was solved after we removed maven-compiler-plugin `<fork>true</fork>` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Open project Settings, change project SDK to java 17, will fix your problem.